# virus threat detected in /usr/lib/shim

Tags: security, malware, antivirus, clamtk

I recently ran a virus scan with `clamtk` and was pleased that not much came up except for one system folder:

`/usr/lib/shim` with the following files being flagged:

```
fallback.efi.signed
MokManager.efi.signed
shim.efi
shim.efi.signed
```

All of which had the same status:

**PUA.Win32.Packer.PrivateExeProte-7**

A quick google search into into what these files are says something about  "Secure Boot chain-loading bootloader (Microsoft-signed binary)"
 which doesn't sound  like something that should be removed. This also sounds like something I don't want to have infected.

I uploaded the files to https://www.virustotal.com/ and was informed that the files are 'probably harmless' . Is this a false positive?

Can anyone please tell me what to do here? Has my system been compromised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PUA stands for potentially unwanted application. Clamtk is able to detect them -see the options. The packer stands for a code that is extracting the main code during the run.

If you are unsure about the binary file, you can upload it to virustotal.com to see what other antivirus engines are saying.

Comment: 'probably harmelss'